# Java duplicates in integer array

Tags: java

I need to find if an `int[]` array contains duplicates. I can not use collections.

My solution (which does not work) is:

```
boolean containsDuplicates(int[]list1, int[]list2) {
  if (list1.length != list2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] != list2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Did you write this code? If yes, then what's the problem changing it to accept `int[]`.

Comment: Are there any memory constraints to the problem?

Comment: Why can't two lists of different lenghts contain same ints?

Answer (score 2):

A solution, not the best in computation cycles but without memory overhead:

1. A loop to iterate the array A from 0 to N with index M
2. A nested loop to iterate A from M+1 to N with index S
3. if( A[M]=A[S] ) return true
4. return false (no duplicates found)

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean hasDuplicates(int []inArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inArray.length - 1; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < inArray.length; j++)
            if(inArray[i] == inArray[j])
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doing other peoples homework, especially with direct answers, helps nobody :<